# Using Promises and Promise.all Inside forEach Loops

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise, fetch-api

I am amending a locally stored variable (data) using this function, and it works. But because it's not setup with Promises yet, the data is retrieved after the page loads, so it is not shown. I've gone through several iterations of this with attempts at using Promises to get this working properly, but haven't been able to get it right.

I'm assuming there should be a Promise.all for the projects.map area, but then I'm not sure where it gets resolved, and how it's called.

```
function getProjects() {
  fetch('http://localhost:8888/wp-json/wp/v2/categories')
  .then(r => r.json())
  .then(categories => {
    categories.forEach(category => {
      data.forEach(service => {
        if(service.service_name == category.name) {
          fetch(`http://localhost:8888/wp-json/wp/v2/projects?
categories=${category.id}`)
          .then(r => r.json())
          .then(projects => {
            service.projects = projects.map(project => {
              // if true, add PROJECT to THAT service
                if(project.better_featured_image) {
                  return {
                    project_name: project.title.rendered,
                    project_desc: project.content.rendered,
                    project_img: 
project.better_featured_image.media_details.sizes.medium.source_url
                  }
                } else {
                  return {
                    project_name: project.title.rendered,
                    project_desc: project.content.rendered
                  }
                }
            })
          })
        }
      })
    })
  })
}
```

var data is set up like this so that each project needs to be attached to a service based on category.

```
var data = [
  {
    service_name: 'Service 1',
    service_desc: 'Desc',
    service_img: 'Img URL',
    projects: [
      {
        project_name: 'Project 1',
        project_desc: 'Desc',
        project_img: 'Img URL'
      }
  }
]
```

Comment: You can't use promises inside a foreach, well not in the way your wanting.  If you did use foreach you could create a promise chain, or an array of promise for Promise.all.. But the way I like to do it is using Promise based map. eg.  Like Bluebirds promise.map, that has the added bonus of a a `concurrency` option.

Comment: Damn, how many server hits does this generate! You should have an endpoint that returns all this data in a single hit.

Comment: @Zze Unfortunately it's the Wordpress API so I don't control the endpoints

Answer (score 0):

Use `Promise.all()`

```
function getProjects() {
    fetch('http://localhost:8888/wp-json/wp/v2/categories')
        .then(r => r.json())
        .then(categories => {
            var promises = [];
            categories.forEach(category => {
                data.forEach(service => {
                    if (service.service_name == category.name) {
                        promises.push(fetch(`http://localhost:8888/wp-json/wp/v2/projects?categories=${category.id}`)
                            .then(r => r.json()));
                    }
                })
            })
            return Promise.all(promises)
        }).then(data => {
            // Get result of all call 
        })
}
```